# Change font family of all div/span/everything in Wordpress blog

Tags: wordpress

I have a WordPress blog. I use a wide variety of fonts. Now I want to specify one font - say "Calibri" - and then all the font families for all elements on my sute change to Calibri, overriding the specified CSS.

I know I can do this by going into the stylesheet and manually finding each font family and replacing it. Is there any shortcut to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't really a shortcut, but if you need to force font-family and don't want to remove those currently there:

```
* { font-family:"Calibri" !important }
```

This is assuming that you don't use !important for font-family anywhere else, because since * will have lower specificity the line above won't work for that element.

I would avoid overuse of !important rules, definitely restrict it to just this case if you can.

Answer (score 0):

Just delete all the old `font-family` rules, then add `body{font-family:"Calibri"}`.

Comment: I have deifned font-family at least at 200 different places, hence was looking for a different way to do this

Comment: @Yasser [Search and replace,](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=search+and+replace) broham.